# Attempting to render a web view using an iOS simulator with an Expo project results in a crash

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-webview

Bug description:
Attempting to render a web view using an iOS simulator with an Expo project results in a crash. We are trying to render a very simple text-only web page containing our apps privacy policy. The issue does not occur on Android. I am using `import { RichEditor } from 'react-native-pell-rich-editor';` , this package has dependency on `react-native-webview` so sometimes using this component also crashed the app in ios.

crash report:

> ------------------------------------- Translated Report (Full Report Below) -------------------------------------  Incident Identifier:
> 68A0A5FE-D4D7-4DAB-B8AD-9878C93CDBF8 CrashReporter Key:
> EF76ADD0-67A1-7D86-B8F7-3645C73793C7 Hardware Model:      Mac14,10
> Process:             ioswebview [48016] Path:
> /Users/USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/2D29BE6A-CA16-4331-A2A9-F9F44A251A0D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3434822E-5A16-4CE5-9F14-8252726CD553/ioswebview.app/ioswebview
> Identifier:          com.rob.caldecott.ioswebview Version:
> 1.0.0 (1) Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native) Role:                Foreground Parent Process:      launchd_sim [25287] Coalition:
> com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.2D29BE6A-CA16-4331-A2A9-F9F44A251A0D
> [52287] Responsible Process: SimulatorTrampoline [3460]  Date/Time:
> 2023-10-17 09:19:57.5162 +0100 Launch Time:         2023-10-17
> 09:19:45.1917 +0100 OS Version:          macOS 13.6 (22G120) Release
> Type:        User Report Version:      104  Exception Type:
> EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at
> 0x000000000000001e Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001,
> 0x000000000000001e VM Region Info: 0x1e is not in any region.  Bytes
> before following region: 105553518919650       REGION TYPE
> START - END         [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
> UNUSED SPACE AT START --->         MALLOC_NANO (reserved)
> 600018000000-600020000000 [128.0M] rw-/rwx SM=NUL  ...(unallocated)
> Termination Reason: SIGNAL 11 Segmentation fault: 11 Terminating
> Process: exc handler [48016]  Triggered by Thread:  0  Kernel Triage:
> VM - (arg = 0x0) pmap_enter retried due to resource shortage VM - (arg
> = 0x0) pmap_enter retried due to resource shortage VM - (arg = 0x0) pmap_enter retried due to resource shortage VM - (arg = 0x0)
> pmap_enter retried due to resource shortage VM - (arg = 0x0)
> pmap_enter retried due to resource shortage   Thread 0 Crashed::
> Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread 0   libobjc.A.dylib
> 0x1800317a0 object_isClass + 16 1   Foundation                              0x180b31924 KVO_IS_RETAINING_ALL_OBSERVERS_OF_THIS_OBJECT_IF_IT_CRASHES_AN_OBSERVER_WAS_OVERRELEASED_OR_SMASHED
>
> - 72 2   Foundation                              0x180b2e280 NSKeyValueWillChangeWithPerThreadPendingNotifications + 280 3   WebKit
>   0x107c7426c WebKit::PageClientImplCocoa::gpuProcessDidExit() + 40 4   WebKit                                0x107e05a30
>   WebKit::WebPageProxy::gpuProcessExited(WebKit::ProcessTerminationReason)
> - 52 5   WebKit                                  0x107e26e0c WebKit::WebProcessPool::gpuProcessExited(int,
>   WebKit::ProcessTerminationReason) + 376 6   WebKit
>   0x107e81eb8 WebKit::GPUProcessProxy::gpuProcessExited(WebKit::ProcessTerminationReason)
> - 220 7   WebKit                                 0x107e82020 WebKit::GPUProcessProxy::processIsReadyToExit() + 132 8   WebKit
>   0x107a7ead0 WebKit::GPUProcessProxy::didReceiveMessage(IPC::Connection&,
>   IPC::Decoder&) + 172 9   WebKit
>   0x1081d0210
>   IPC::Connection::dispatchMessage(std::__1::unique_ptr<IPC::Decoder,
>   std::__1::default_deleteIPC::Decoder>) + 640 10  WebKit
>   0x1081d2474 WTF::Detail::CallableWrapper<IPC::Connection::enqueueIncomingMessage(std::__1::unique_ptr<IPC::Decoder,
>   std::__1::default_deleteIPC::Decoder>)::$_15, void>::call() + 188 11
>   JavaScriptCore                           0x105ee4958
>   WTF::RunLoop::performWork() + 172 12  JavaScriptCore
>   0x105ee5570 WTF::RunLoop::performWork(void*) + 32 13  CoreFoundation
>   0x18039ac6c **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 24 14  CoreFoundation                          0x18039abb4 __CFRunLoopDoSource0
> - 172 15  CoreFoundation                         0x18039a324 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 232 16  CoreFoundation                          0x180394958 __CFRunLoopRun + 748 17  CoreFoundation
>   0x180394254 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 584 18  GraphicsServices
>   0x188eb7c9c GSEventRunModal + 160 19  UIKitCore                             0x110ffeff0 -[UIApplication _run] + 868 20  UIKitCore                               0x111002f3c UIApplicationMain + 124 21  ioswebview                              0x10009f4e0 main + 96 22  dyld_sim                              0x102561514 start_sim + 20 23  dyld
>   0x102669f28 start + 2236

Did anyone face the same issue?